# I have a voxel engine that I am trying to optimize with Don't Repeat Yourself. Is there any way to fix this long-running mess?

Tags: c#, game-engine, voxel

For every single block type, I have to repeat a section of code that generates each face multiple times. I know there has to be a better way, but I did try to place the sections into a function per face and it errored out hard, even using a ref.

```
                    if (block.blockType == 1 && top == 0)
                {
                    vertexIndex = vertices.Count;
                    vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y + 1, z));
                    vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y + 1, z + 1));
                    vertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 1, y + 1, z + 1));
                    vertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 1, y + 1, z));
                    // first triangle for the block top
                    triangles.Add(vertexIndex);
                    triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 1);
                    triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 2);
                    // second triangle for the block top
                    triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 2);
                    triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 3);
                    triangles.Add(vertexIndex);
                    // add UV
                    uvs.Add(new Vector2 (0.125f, 0.0f));
                    uvs.Add(new Vector2 (0.25f, 0.0f));
                    uvs.Add(new Vector2 (0.25f, 0.125f));
                    uvs.Add(new Vector2 (0.125f, 0.125f));

                }
```

This is a typical section (sans StackOverflow formatting) - what could I do with it?

Comment: What is stopping you from extracting the method? Show your attempts and explain what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should handle your 3 arrays, (Vertex / vertex indexes / uv coords) within a single flat array, that you pre-fill with 0 before filling it with actual values.
   Performances would skyrocket.
2. I wonder if your vertex index won't contain each time the same sequences. You could only store ONE vertexIndex instead of the 6 numbers (+0 +1 +2 +2 +3 +0). But maybe you want to have the indexes at hand for webgl.

.
To factorize, i would make 6 of functions like this one :

```
Vertices.prototype.AddVerticesUP = function(x, y, z) {
     var currIndex = this.lastIndex;
     var vertArr = this.verticeArray;
     vertArr[currIndex]=vertArr[currIndex+3]=
           vertArr[currIndex+6]=vertArr[currIndex+9] = x;
      vertArr[currIndex+1]=vertArr[currIndex+4]=
          vertArr[currIndex+7]=vertArr[currIndex+10] = y;
     vertArr[currIndex+2]=vertArr[currIndex+5]=
           vertArr[currIndex+8]=vertArr[currIndex+11] =z;      
     // first point
     vertArr[currIndex+1]++;
     // second
     vertArr[currIndex+4]++; vertArr[currIndex+5]++;
     // third
     vertArr[currIndex+6]++;vertArr[currIndex+7]++;vertArr[currIndex+8]++;
     // fourth
     vertArr[currIndex+9]++;vertArr[currIndex+10]++;    
     this.lastIndex +=12;     
}
```

then build an array out of them :

```
Vertices.prototype.AddVertices= [ Vertices.prototype.AddVerticesUP,
                                  Vertices.prototype.AddVerticesDOWN, 
                                  Vertices.prototype.AddVerticesLEFT,
                                  Vertices.prototype.AddVerticesRIGHT,
                                  Vertices.prototype.AddVerticesFRONT,
                                  Vertices.prototype.AddVerticesBACK] ;
```

To use that array, if dir is the direction, just do :

```
Vertices.AddVertices [dir] ( x,y,z );
```

For your uv coordinates, you can simplify also, since all coordinates are axis aligned and square. Signature could be : uvs.addSquareUVs( baseU, baseV, size ).  But if guess right, the coordinates depends only on side + block type. So you could make 6 functions with the same mechanism as above, and the signature would be `uvs.addUV [dir] (block type)` or `uvs.addUV [dir] [block type] ()` .

now the 6 if/else for each side, multiplied by the number of block type can be greatly simplified to just this code :

```
vertexIndex = vertices.Count;
vertices.AddVertices [direction] ( x, y, z);
triangles.AddSquareStartingAt(vertexIndex);
uvs.addSquareUVs [direction] [block.blockType] ();
```

Comment: All of that reads like Javascript to me... the engine itself is written in C#.

Comment: Oh yes i wrote it in js, but translation to C# is easy i guess, and same remarks apply for performances.

Comment: What do you think of what i suggest ? Should i translate from Javascript ? Vertices.prototype.method means static method (or property) of Vertices. The rest is quite the same in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

For vertex adding and uv coordinates you could define static collections somewhere:

```
public static readonly Vector3[] Corners = new Vector3[]{new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 0)};
public static readonly Vector2[] UVCorners = new Vector2[]{new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0.125f, 0), new Vector2(0.125f, 0.125f), new Vector2(0, 0.125f)};
```

And then you can make the section more compact:

```
            if (block.blockType == 1 && top == 0)
            {
                vertexIndex = vertices.Count;
                Vector3 origin = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                foreach (Vector3 corner in Corners) vertices.Add(origin + corner);
                // first triangle for the block top
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex);
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 1);
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 2);
                // second triangle for the block top
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 2);
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 3);
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex);
                // add UV
                Vector2 uvOrigin = new Vector2(0.125f, 0);
                foreach (Vector2 uvCorner in UVCorners) uvs.Add(uvOrigin + uvCorner);
            }
```